# How to remove project in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

If I'm closing a project and then just delete the project folder, after PyCharm restarts an empty project folder is created again.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Just follow these steps in order. They assume you currently have the project open in a PyCharm window:

1. Close your project by clicking on File -> Close Project
2. Locate your project in the PyCharm file directory
3. Delete your project's directory

I agree that PyCharm's handling of what should be a very simple procedure is crappy. Maybe this will be improved in the future?

Comment: File->Close project is not an option on pycharm 5. Pressing the delete on project selection works (without deleting files)

Answer (score 40):

If you want to remove the project from the recent projects list, just highlight the project with your mouse and hit the del key.

Comment: Works great... but in case anyone from PyCharm/JetBrains is paying attention - this *REALLY* needs to be made better - a tool tip, a note at the bottom of the list, something anything!

Comment: Had the same problem. After some trial and error realized that Del does not work for the first project in the list. For that one only File > Close is the option as mentioned above.

Comment: On a Mac, delete project from recents list with the combination of the "fn" key and "Del" see  http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/PyCharm-1267

Comment: I am on pycharm 2016.2.3 
none of the below are working
1. left click on the project once and hit del
2. right click on the project has no remove option

Comment: @GajendraDAmbi please see if you selected the "project" and not the "project files". Both show a similar kind of view in the project windows. When you select "project", you can press delete to detach the project from.

Comment: This will not delete the project. It only removes it from the *Recent Projects* menu.

Comment: Have the same problem as GajendraDAmbi. `File > Close Project` has apparently been removed while hitting delete doesn't work for the first opened project. To get to a single project, I have to close all projects, open the desired project (which also opens other projects I had open) and then hit delete for other projects. Rather annoying.

Answer (score 11):

This is for **PyCharm 2019.1**, but I can bet this will work in previous versions.

I am assuming you are in a Unix based operating system (macOs or any Linux distribution). I am also assuming you have currently opened the project you want to remove.

1. Close the project by going to `File → Close Project`:

   [image]
2. Remove the project from Pycharm's Welcome Window:

[image]

3. Locate your project and delete it, you can use several alternatives, but I encourage you to use the following

```
$ rm -rf /path/to/your/project/directory
```

The previous command will work in macOS and Linux. In Windows, you can delete it manually by locating the projects directory using File Explorer.

That's it, the project has been completely deleted!

Answer (score 6):

1. click the project you want to remove.
2. menu bar Edit-> Remove from Project View.

Answer (score 5):

There is a difference between **PyCharm projects** and the **list of recently opened projects** (*File → Open recent...*):

- The **PyCharm project** is simply an **arbitrary folder<sup>1</sup> with the appropriate `.idea` subfolder in it.**
- The **list of recently opened projects** is simply the **list of paths to *some* of such folders**.

PyCharm *does not keep the list of **all** projects,* so you may safely delete a project folder (or its `.idea` subfolder) from your file system.

But if you have a bad luck, the path to your project directory is already listed in the list of recently opened projects, and if you try opening it with ***File → Open recent...***, then

1. in *older* version of PyCharm, the deleted folder is re-created (as a new folder with only the `.idea` subfolder in it),
2. in *newer* versions of PyCharm you get the prompt similar as

   > The path C:\Users\you\PycharmProjects\deleted_project does not exist.
   > If it is on a removable or network drive, please make sure that the drive is
   > connected.

   with buttons "OK" and "Remove From List", so you may simply remove the deleted folder from the list,
3. in *all* version of PyCharm, if you deleted only the `.idea` subfolder, it is silently re-created (but all your project settings are lost, of course).

To prevent from the uncomfortable consequence of the 1<sup>st</sup> possibility of using the ***File → Open recent...*** to re-create already deleted project, follow e.g. the first two instructions in the [Simin Jie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49744294/7023590).

---

<sup>1</sup> generally a subfolder of the `PyCharmProjects` folder in your user profile directory (e.g. if you created it with *File → New Project...* and accepted the offered default path).

Answer (score 4):

Version 2017.2.1

1. Press Alt+1 to bring the project pane, and make sure you're in
   **Project** view (not **Project Files** view).
2. Select the desired project, and choose "Delete from project
   view" from the context menu (right click). You can also use Delete
   key.

Comment: This should be the correct answer as your using pycharm to fix the problem, and not a hack.

Comment: I had to first remove the subproject from Settings | Project <my project> | Project Structure | Content Root. There was a little x on the right. Then I could "Remove it from project view."

Answer (score 3):

Works for Windows and MacOS.

- `File` -- `Open Recent` -- `Manage Projects`
  [image]
- Cliek `X` to delete from `Recent Projects`
  [image]
- Delete local directory

According to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksbmc0coO4k

Answer (score 2):

In PyCharm 2018 I finally had to resort to deleting .idea folder and the project went away.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the project with your mouse and hit the del key, which works for me.

Comment: I am on pycharm 2016.2.3 
none of the below are working
1. left click on the project once and hit del
2. right click on the project has no remove option

Answer (score 1):

In 2021 maybe another way to do it. My problem was in project with user directory (root was `/Users`) that contains too many not Python files, and it triggers some problems with Git and file index.

What I did:

- show hidden files (`Cmd + Shift + .`),
- find `.idea` directories,
- delete all `.idea` directories.
- open PyCharm and add project from correct directory.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

In version 2017.2.1

File → Close Project

You will be taken to the start-up window, where you can see the projects you've created on the left. You can then delete a project by clicking the cross sign ('x') following the project name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My solution was:

1. Close project.
2. Rename the folder you want to dissapear
3. Open pycharm project. A dialog will be shown asking if you want Pycharm remove the folder. Answer: yes.

That is enough.