# Pycharm - how do I remove the _first_ project on the project view?

Tags: pycharm

Coming from eclipse pycharm's way still escapes me. So as we read here: [How to remove project PyCharm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839182/how-to-remove-project-pycharm#comment41674340_23500783) one can only close the first project on the "project view" - there is no delete option.

So how do I remove the *first project* ? Am I missing something in Pycharm's logic ?

Comment: This is something that has been bugging me for a while now... very frustrating and seems like a simple bug that they could fix

Comment: @nmz787: Opened an issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16227

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems not possible at the moment. I opened an issue [PY-16227](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-16227).